# Step function (staircase function) construction by using signum functions

Tags: functions

Is it possible to construct the following staircase function by using only signum functions? As can be seen in the not so pleasant picture the steps are located at the points $(x_i,y_i)$ for $i=1,\ldots,n$. If it is not possible using only signum functions can we at least use signum functions in combination with some other elementary functions to reproduce this behaviour.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is possible. Nota that the unit step function can be written as
$$s(x)=\frac{1}{2}(\textrm{sgn}(x)+1)$$
As a result the function depicted in the above Figure can be written as
$$f(x)=y_1+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^n{(y_{i+1}-y_i)\left[\textrm{sgn}(x-x_i)+1\right]}$$